# trying to create a like button counter in mysql table, but UPDATE SET doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, counter, updates

so I'm working on a school project to create a portfolio showcase website, one of the main required functions is to create a like button for the images. I'm using xampp to host the files and database. I'm trying to make it so tat each time a person clicks the button, it would add +1 to the 'likes' column in the table, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm still new to this so thorough explanation would be appreciated.
this is the block of code that as the

```
<h1><?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?>'s work </h1>
<?php



$username ="root";
$password ="";
$hostname ="localhost";

//connection to database

$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password)
or die("unable to connect to my SQL");

$lastid = $_SESSION['user'];

$image3 = "SELECT * FROM staff.image WHERE `user`='$lastid' ";
$r=mysqli_query($conn, $image3);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
{
?>


<ul id="rig">
    <li>
        <a class="rig-cell">
            <?php   echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['img'] ) . '" align="middle" height=50% " />'; ?> 

            <span class="rig-overlay"></span>
            <span class="rig-text"> <?php   echo $row['img_name']."<br>"; ?></span>




        </a>
            <form method="POST" action=""  class="radiowrapper" >
            <input class="like" type="submit" name="problem" value="<?php echo $row['img_id']; ?>" id="name_<?php echo $row['img_name']; ?>">
            </form>
    </li>
</ul>   

<?php
    if (isset ($_POST['problem']))
    {
        echo $sql = "UPDATE staff.image SET likes='".$row['likes']."'+1 WHERE img_id='".$row['img_id']."'";

    }
}
?>
```

I have another file that lets the user upload the image of his choice, and writes a name for it, and saves it in staff.image. here some screenshots

[image]

[image]

I don't really understand the problem and I've been trying different ways to write the UPDATE function but to no avail. if I'm unclear on something r you require more details I'll post it right away.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: `echo $sql` look at that again and then ask yourself. Plus, you never queried that

Comment: Surely this is what TUTORIALS are for

Comment: I added the echo on purpose to see if the $_POST variable is correct, also if you look at the table id you'll see that I've actually tried 80+ times to make this work and watched many videos explaining it, from my understanding the code should be correct, I'm just a student that is still learning so helping and explaining what my problem so I can learn from it would be appreciated

Comment: @user3158009 is right, he is admittedly new to programming and is asking for guidance, don't punish him for his attempts.

Comment: @user3158009 regardless of what the echo was for. `$sql` is just a string...it doesnt do anything by itself. You need to send that to `mysqli_query()` if you want the statement to be executed. I also doubt that you want to call `mysqli_query` in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wondering why it's echoing the query?

Simple, you told it to:

```
if (isset ($_POST['problem']))
{
    echo $sql = "UPDATE staff.image SET likes='".$row['likes']."'+1 WHERE img_id='".$row['img_id']."'";
    ^^^^

}
```

Plus, you never executed the query.

So,

```
//added this part after the while loop

if (isset ($_POST['problem']))
    {
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE staff.image SET likes=likes+1 WHERE img_id='".$_POST['problem']."'");


    if($sql){
     echo "Success";
    }
    else {
       echo "<i>Houston, we have a problem:</i> " . mysqli_error($conn);
      }
}
```

- Use [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) for truthness.

Comment: I would have gone for `SET likes = likes + 1` personally. Then you only need the Row key for the query to work

Comment: @RiggsFolly True, yet hard to say what they really want to do and what the schema looks like.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Looking at the screenshot again; you're most likely right, it should more than likely be `SET likes = likes + 1`.

Comment: thanks for the help guys, when I tried making it likes=likes+ 1 it kept addign 6 everytime, which I'm guessing is the number of images/rows in my table.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yup, just added more images to my table and tested it out ,and `likes = likes+1` adds the number of rows in my table for some reason.
I'm currently using this line of code 
`if (isset ($_POST['problem']))
{
 $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE staff.image SET likes=likes+1 WHERE img_id='".$_POST['problem']."'");
     
}`

Comment: @user3158009 Yeah, Riggs caught that; thanks for the edit, *cheers* Glad it all worked out.